# $\mathbb{E}[f(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{n}) \mid \sigma(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_{n-1})] =\mathbb{E}[f(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{n}) \mid X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{n-1} ]$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

$f$ is a bounded measurable functions and the $X_i$'s are independent

to prove the above one must show the following equality : $$I = J$$
where : 
$$I=\int_{A \in  \sigma(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_{n-1})} \mathbb{E}[f(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n) \mid X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{n-1} ]d \mathbb{P}$$

$$J=\int_{A \in  \sigma(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_{n-1})} f(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n) d \mathbb{P}$$

clearly if $\sigma(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_{n-1}) \subset\sigma(X_1+X_2+ \cdots+X_{n-1})$

then the equality holds

and that inclusion is actually correct for the following argument,

elements of $\sigma(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_{n-1})$ are all intersections of elements of $\sigma(X_1+X_2+ \cdots+X_{n-1})$

is this right ? can someone correct any falseness I said ?

Comment: It is not true that $\sigma(X_1,X_2,...,X_n) \subset \sigma(X_1+X_2+...+X_n)$ except in some trivial cases.

Comment: Moer generally, if $X$ is independent of $\mathcal G$ and $Y$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable, then $E(f(X+Y)\mid\mathcal G)=g(Y)$ where $g(y)=E(f(X+y))$, hence $E(f(X+Y)\mid\mathcal G)=E(f(X+Y)\mid Y)$.